# Can't convert docx to pdf in oracle weblogic

Tags: documents4j

I try to convert docx to pdf using documents4j. At first, I try it on my local pc and it works perfectly. But when I upload it in weblogic, it says this error

```
    com.documents4j.conversion.msoffice.MicrosoftWordBridge : Unable to run script: /tmp/1485771859333-0/word_start103185801.vbs java.io.IOException: Could not execute [cmd, /S, /C, ""/tmp/1485771859333-0/word_start103185801.vbs""] in /tmp/1485771859333-0.
```

Comment: Did you read the error message? Seems to be an issue that "weblogic" can't execute the necessary commands...

Comment: I read from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/documents4j/dQTzVBHLuXk

"You need to run a server on a machine that has MS Word installed". maybe this is the reason, but I don't know if its true

Answer (score 0):

This can mean different things:

1. The .NET runtime is not installed on the Weblogic server.
2. You do not have rights to execute scripts via .NET on this server.

documents4j is a Java library but binds .NET commands and needs an MS Word installation. Also, make sure that you completed any MS Word Wizard that can appear right after installation of a new copy.

Comment: thanks I've told my boss about this and he decided to use windows server. whats the minimum version of MS Word to make it works?